# difference between python2 and python3 - int() and input()

Tags: python, python-3.4

I wrote below python code.
And I found that python2 and python3 has totally difference running result for input of 1.1.
Why is there such difference between python2 and python3? 
For me, int(1.1) should be 1, then position is valid index 1 within range 0,1,2. So  can you please explain why python3 has such result?

```
s=[1,2,3]
while True:
  value=input()
  print('value:',value)
  try:
    position=int(value)
    print('position',position)
    print('result',s[position])
  except IndexError as err:
    print('out of index')
  except Exception as other:
    print('sth else broke',other)


$ python temp.py
1.1
('value:', 1.1)
('position', 1)
('result', 2)


$ python3 temp.py
1.1
value: 1.1
sth else broke invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.1'
```

Comment: To make it really work, you can do position = int(float(value))

Comment: Can you try verifying type of value?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is `intput()` converts the value to an number for python2 and a string for python 3.

`int()` of a non int string returns an error, while int() of a float does not.

Convert the input value to a float using either:

```
value=float(input())
```

or, better (safer) yet

```
position=int(float(value))
```

EDIT: And best of all, avoid using `input` since it uses an `eval` and is unsafe.  As Tadhg suggested, the best solution is:

```
#At the top:
try:
    #in python 2 raw_input exists, so use that
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    #in python 3 we hit this case and input is already raw_input
    pass

...
    try:
        #then inside your try block, convert the string input to an number(float) before going to an int
        position = int(float(value))
```

From the Python Docs:

> PEP 3111: `raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`. That is, the new `input()`
>   function reads  a line from `sys.stdin` and returns it with the trailing
>   newline stripped. It raises  `EOFError` if the input is terminated
>   prematurely. To get the old behavior of `input()`,  use `eval(input())`.

Comment: even safer would be to do `try:input = raw_input ; except NameError: pass` and then treat the input as a string in both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the Python 3 release notes. In particular, the `input()` function (which is considered dangerous) was removed. In its stead, the safer `raw_input()` function was renamed to `input()`.

In order to write code for both versions, only rely on `raw_input()`. Add the following to the top of your file:

```
try:
    # replace unsafe input() function
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    # raw_input doesn't exist, the code is probably
    # running on Python 3 where input() is safe
    pass
```

BTW: Your example code isn't minimal. If you had further reduced the code, you would have found that in one case `int()` operates on a `float` and in the other on a `str` which would then have brought you to the different things that `input()` returns. A look at the docs would then have given you the final hint.